# Access 'this' Inside Promise

Tags: typescript, angular, scoping

In the typescript function below, 'this' doesn't resolve to the instance of EmailValidator. How can I correct this function so it resolves to the correct instance of EmailVaildator and in turn, so that I can access _registerServices?

```
class EmailValidator {

    constructor(private _registerServices: RegisterServices) { }

    isAvailable(c: AbstractControl): Promise<ValidationResult> {
        let q = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this._registerServices.emailIsAvailable(antiForgeryToken(), c.value)
                .then(result => {
                    // Need to actually check the result.
                    resolve({ "emailtaken": true })
                },
                error => {
                    // Need to communicate the server error? Probably not.
                    resolve({ "servererror": true })
                });
        });

        return q;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm. It looks like the fat arrow should already be doing that. And looking at the generated Javascript, it does seem to alias `this` properly. Are you sure that's the issue you are seeing?

Comment: @Thilo I've since discovered the problem is a bit hidden and that the issue was elsewhere. I've discovered how to correct my issue, but there are details around 'why' the problem occurred that I'd really appreciate some guidance on. I'll post my solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are losing `this`, because you are passing around the `isAvailableEmail` as a "raw" function here:

```
email: ['', Validators.required, this._emailValidator.isAvailableEmail]
```

You can fix this by binding it to `this` (using the fat arrow):

```
email: ['', Validators.required,
  (control) => { this._emailValidator.isAvailableEmail(control) }
]
```

Comment: Thanks Thilo. I like your solution - it's the smallest change - but will stick with mine, because it's consistent with how the Angular team appear to have implemented their validators. I'll makr your answer as the accepted one because it best answers the original question.

Comment: Note that they have "static" functions like `Validators.required` that don't need to be configured, and validator factories that generate validator function that capture all their configuration, like `Validators.minLength(8)`. You could do something like `EmailValidator(registerServices)` to produce a function that captures the `registerServices` and does what your `isAvailableEmail` does.

Comment: So, a validator should not be a class so much as a function that creates another function (like your `isAvailableEmail`). And that generated function is self-contained.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that the 'this' reference was undefined even if it was used as follows:

```
class EmailValidator {

    constructor(private _registerServices: RegisterServices) { }

    isAvailable(c: AbstractControl): EmailValidator {
        return this; // 'This' is undefined!
    }
}
```

I gather this has something to do with how the method was called, perhaps passing a non-static method where a static method was expected:

```
...
this.registerForm = fb.group({
    email: ['', Validators.required, this._emailValidator.isAvailableEmail],
    password: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)])],
    phoneNumber: ['', Validators.required],
    country: ['', Validators.required]
    });
...
```

If someone could offer some guidance on what's occurring here, that'd be fantastic.

## My Solution

I reordered my code and produced the following:

```
class EmailValidator {

    static isAvailableEmail(services: RegisterServices): (AbstractControl) => Promise<ValidationResult> {
        let g = (c: AbstractControl) => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                services.emailIsAvailable(antiForgeryToken(), c.value)
                    .then(result => {
                        // Need to actually check the result.
                        resolve({ "emailtaken": true })
                    },
                    error => {
                        // Need to communicate the server error? Probably not.
                        resolve({ "servererror": true })
                    });
            });
        };

        return g;
    }
}
```

And amended its usage:

```
...
this.registerForm = fb.group({
    email: ['', Validators.required,
        EmailValidator.isAvailableEmail(this._registerService)],
    password: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)])],
    phoneNumber: ['', Validators.required],
    country: ['', Validators.required]
    });
...
```

Which works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You have the problem because you are passing the value of `isAvailable` which is a function. You are not executing it, you are just passing the reference to the function.

One way to solve it is as in [@Thilo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37288859/3125880)

Another way is to assign `isAvailable` to a lambda expression instead of a function. like this:

```
class EmailValidator {

    constructor(private _registerServices: RegisterServices) { }

    isAvailable = (c: AbstractControl): Promise<ValidationResult> => {
        let q = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this._registerServices.emailIsAvailable(antiForgeryToken(), c.value)
                .then(result => {
                    // Need to actually check the result.
                    resolve({ "emailtaken": true })
                },
                error => {
                    // Need to communicate the server error? Probably not.
                    resolve({ "servererror": true })
                });
        });

        return q;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would offer to write it a bit different

```
class EmailValidator {

    constructor(private _registerServices: RegisterServices) { }

    isAvailable(c: AbstractControl): Promise<ValidationResult> {
        return this._registerServices.emailIsAvailable(antiForgeryToken(), c.value)
            .then(result => {
                // Need to actually check the result.
                return { "emailtaken": true }
            })
 // shorter .then(result => ({ "emailtaken": true }))
            .catch(error => {
                // Need to communicate the server error? Probably not.
                return { "servererror": true }
            });
 // shorter .catch(error => ({ "servererror": true }))

        });

    }
}
```